# How can I customize the "go to slide number" navigation symbol

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am using a reduced version of the navigation symbols bar that only includes `\insertslidenavigationsymbol`. My presentation only shows the frame numbers (instead of slide numbers) because I use many overlays and the number of slides grows too large. The problem is that if someone in the public ask me to go to a specific frame number (since this is the number they will see), then the navigation button doesn't take me to frame I want to go.

Is there a way to customize the `\insertslidenavigationsymbol` option so that it takes me to a frame number instead of a slide number?

In the following example you will see that if you go to slide 3 using the navigation symbol, it will take you to page 3 in frame 2 (this is the expected behavior, I guess). However, I want it to go to **frame 3** instead. Any ideas? I tried with `\insertframenavigationsymbol` but that one only let me go to previous/next frame, not to a specific frame number.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}

{
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{frame number and last}{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
   \hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number and last]{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{This is frame 1}
    \onslide<1-2>{Some text\\}
    \onslide<2>{\invisible<1>{
    Some more text}}
  \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{This is frame 2}
    This is frame 2
   \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{This is frame 3}
    This is frame 3
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following solution uses JavaScript to jump to the specified frame.
First the starting page numbers of each frame are remembered (in macro `\FrPg@List`).
At the end of the document these data are written as JavaScript object `FrameList`.
Also a function `GoToFrame` is defined that first asks the user for the frame
that he wants to visit. After some validation of the answer the page number is
calculated and the frame is viewed by a destination name that beamer sets for
each page (`Navigation` + page number). If the user uses a frame number less than
the first frame, then the very first page is selected. If the frame number is too
large, then the starting page of the last frame is used.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\def\FrPg@List{}
\def\FrPg@Max{-2147483647}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifnum\FrPg@Max<\value{framenumber}%
    \xdef\FrPg@Max{\the\value{framenumber}}%
  \fi
  \ltx@IfUndefined{FrPg@\number\value{framenumber}}{%
    \expandafter
    \xdef\csname FrPg@\number\value{framenumber}\endcsname{%
      \number\value{page}%
    }%
    \ifx\FrPg@List\ltx@empty
      \xdef\FrPg@List{%
        \number\value{framenumber}:\number\value{page}%
      }%
    \else
      \xdef\FrPg@List{%
        \FrPg@List
        ,\number\value{framenumber}:\number\value{page}%
      }%
    \fi
  }{}%
}
\def\FrPg@Script{FrameNavigation}
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \immediate\pdfobj{(%
    var FrameList={\FrPg@List};%
    var FrameMax=\FrPg@Max;%
    function GoToFrame(){%
      var frame=app.response({%
        % cQuestion:"Which frame?",%
        cTitle:"Go To  Frame",%
        cLabel:"Frame:"%
      });%
      if(frame==null)return;%
      var result=frame.match(/%
        ^%
        \ltx@backslashchar\ltx@backslashchar d+%
        $%
      /);%
      if(result==null){%
        app.alert("Invalid number!");%
        return;%
      }%
      var page=FrameList[frame];
      if(page==null&&frame>FrameMax)%
        page=FrameList[FrameMax];%
      if(page==null){%
        if(frame<1){%
          app.execMenuItem("FirstPage");%
          return;%
        }%
        app.alert("Frame `"+frame+"' not found!");%
        return;%
      }%
      this.gotoNamedDest("Navigation"+page);%
    }%
  )}%
  \immediate\pdfobj{%
    <<%
      /S/JS%
      /JS \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R%
    >>%
  }%
  \immediate\pdfobj{%
    <<%
      /Names[(\FrPg@Script)\the\pdflastobj\space0 R]%
    >>%
  }%
  \pdfnames{%
    /JavaScript \the\pdflastobj\space0 R%
  }%
}
\begin{Form}[]
\end{Form}
\def\insertslidenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerslidenavstrong}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerslidenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-20pt%
  \hyperlinkslideprev{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
  % \Acrobatmenu{GoToPage}{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \PushButton[
    borderwidth=0,
    bordercolor=white,
    onclick=GoToFrame();
  ]{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \hyperlinkslidenext{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
  \insertslidenavigationsymbol
}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{frame number and last}{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
   \hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number and last]{}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
  \begin{frame}{This is frame 1}
    \onslide<1-2>{Some text\\}  
    \onslide<2>{\invisible<1>{  
    Some more text}}
  \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{This is frame 2}
    This is frame 2
   \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{This is frame 3}
    This is frame 3
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Heiko. I haven't been able yet to test your answer. It keeps giving me errors for the atveryend package. I downloaded it and  put it in the Miktex installation but still haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: I tried you answer but it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:  
! Undefined control sequence.  
<argument> ... {framenumber}}\fi \ltx@IfUndefined  
                                                  {FrPg@\number \value {fram...  
l.119   \end{frame}  
Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert `\insertframenavigationsymbol` instead of `\insertslidenavigationsymbol` in your `navigation symbols` template:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenavigationsymbol}

{
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{frame number and last}{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
   \hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number and last]{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{This is frame 1}
    \onslide<1-2>{Some text\\}
    \onslide<2>{\invisible<1>{
    Some more text}}
  \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{This is frame 2}
    This is frame 2
   \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{This is frame 3}
    This is frame 3
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to keep the same (Acrobat) pop-up menu provided by *slide navigation symbols*, you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\makeatletter
\def\insertmycustomframenavigationsymbol{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{-1.5pt}{20pt}{5.5pt}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerframenavstrong}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}
    \pgfuseobject{beamerframenavlight}%
  \end{pgfpicture}\kern-20pt%
  %\hyperlinkframestartprev{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
  \hyperlinkframeendprev{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
  \Acrobatmenu{GoToPage}{\beamer@linkspace{8pt}}%
  \hyperlinkframestartnext{\beamer@linkspace{6pt}}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertmycustomframenavigationsymbol}
{
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{frame number and last}{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
   \hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number and last]{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{This is frame 1}
    \onslide<1-2>{Some text\\}
    \onslide<2>{\invisible<1>{
    Some more text}}
  \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{This is frame 2}
    This is frame 2
   \end{frame}
 \begin{frame}{This is frame 3}
    This is frame 3
 \end{frame}
 \foreach \x in {4,...,10}{
   \begin{frame}{This is frame \x}
     This is frame \x
   \end{frame}
 }
\end{document}
```

**Note:** the correct back link should be `\hyperlinkframestartprev` but this macro is not defined by `beamer`...

Comment: I tried that initially as mentioned in the question. However, that only let me move to previous or next frame, but not to a specific frame number (I can't enter the frame number to which I want to go)

Comment: @SandraC. What kind of interface do you want? A list of numbers? A pop-up menu? A text field with a goto button?

Comment: It will be the last one. Exactly as the text field that appears when `\insertslidenavigationsymbol` is activated

Comment: Thanks @PolGab. It indeed activates the pop up menu exactly how I want it. The problem is that it keeps going to the page number instead of the frame number :-/

Comment: @SandraC. I don't understand your problem... Here, with Adobe Reader 9 (Linux version) and with TeXLive 2012, the popup said "Go To Page -- Page: xx of 3 (4)". If xx is 3, Adobe Reader jumps to "page 3 (4 of 4)" and this page is frame 3.

Comment: Well, that is strange. I tried with Adobe Reader 9 and Acrobat 9 Pro (in Windows). I also tried the pdf viewer in Mac, and in all cases the text box goes to page number instead of frame number, so if I press 3, it shows "This is frame 2". Could be the difference related to the viewer I am employing?

Comment: @SandraC. With Adobe Reader 9 (Linux Version), the page numbers displayed in the toolbar are 1, 1, 2, 3 (with your MWE) and so, it corresponds to frame numbers. And at right of the page number, Adobe Reader displays "(x of 4)" where x is the current slide number.

Comment: Then we definitely see different things. In my Adobe Reader the toolbar keeps counting slides (or pages), so when I move through I see 1,2,3,4 (even though the frame number on the slide goes 1,1,2,3). I guess that is why the Go to Page is still not working for me.

Comment: @SandraC. Ok. I tested with another document (a book with frontmatter et mainmatter) and Adobe Reader (Linux) displays page numbers from "i" to "xvi" (16 pages in frontmatter) then from "1" to last page (pages of mainmatter). Sorry for this long digression.

Comment: Thanks, but does that mean there is no way to fix the code? How can I make it go to frame number?

Comment: @SandraC. With a recent distribution, you can use Heiko's solution using `\hyperlinkframestartnext` and `\hyperlinkframeendrev` instead of `\hyperlinkslidenext` and `\hyperlinkslideprev`.